# Uniqueness of the Smooth Structure on a Handle Attachment

Tags: differential-topology, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds, handle-decomposition

I posted this question on math stack exchange and didn't receive an answer.  If it is too elementary for this forum I will be happy to delete it.

Let $M^m$ be a smooth manifold with boundary. We may form a new *topological* manifold by "adjoining a handle to $M$", I.e. by choosing a smooth map $h : \partial \mathbb{D}^{\mu} \times \mathbb{D}^{\lambda} \rightarrow \partial M$ ($\mu + \lambda = m$) and taking our new manifold to be $M' := M \cup_h \mathbb{D}^{\mu} \times \mathbb{D}^{\lambda}$.

A priori $M'$ is just a *topological* manifold with boundary, however there are many well-known ways to "smooth the corners" of $M'$ (I.e. to endow $M'$ with a smooth structure).  My question is "**what is the right uniqueness statement?**" i.e. how can I formally state that all off these different ways to smooth corners result in diffeomorphic manifolds.

To give a sense for the sort of result I'm hoping for I'll say that I have in mind a statement that begins something like "up to diffeomorphism there is a unique smooth atlas for $M'$ such that the inclusion  $M \subset M'$ is a smooth imbedding and the inclusion $\mathbb{D}^{\mu} \times \mathbb{D}^{\lambda} \subset M'$ is a smooth imbedding of a manifold with corners." That statement is probably nonsense but I just wanted to give a sense for the sort of thing I'd like to be true. Thanks for considering my question.

Comment: I'll post an answer on MSE. 

Comment: The MSE thread is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368640/uniqueness-of-smoothed-corners

Comment: thanks Ryan. Do you think I should leave this one up or delete?

Comment: This is a question where it could be either on MO or MSE as it's a fairly standard grad student question.  Given that you had it up on MSE first, I'd just keep that one and close this one. But it's up to you. 

Comment: Voting to close as "no longer relevant".